# Variable when inserting into model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, model

I have a user model with 5 fruits:

```
User
  fruit_1
  fruit_2
  fruit_3
  fruit_4
  fruit_5
```

Is it possible to do a for-each when inserting into the user model? Like

```
@fruits = ['apple','banana','orange','strawberry','blueberry']

user = User.new

@fruits.each do |a, fruit |
  user.fruit_a = fruit <-- I want a to be the actual variable.
end
```

Comment: This is pretty confusing, could you expand on your question a bit please?

Comment: @matt, hungovered =) Expanded the q a bit. More clear?

Comment: So are you trying to loop through fruit_1 to fruit_5 and assign them within a loop?

Comment: @cyle I have a array with 5 object which I want to assign to the fruits within the user model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@fruits.each_with_index do |fruit, i|
  attrib = "fruit_#{i + 1}"
  user.send(attrib) = fruit
end
```

Comment: That's the way. The "send" function executes the string it gets as an parameter as a command. BTW, having fruit1, fruit2 (...) seems like a bad design, but it's not the issue here :)

Comment: Yep, or simply, `user.send("fruit_#{i+1}") = fruit` inside the loop (cutting out the middle man ;)).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate syntax if you want:

```
user.assign_attributes(Hash[1.upto(@fruits.length).map{|i| ["fruit_#{i}", fruit[i]]}])
```